# Leveraged Trade program

Tags: leverage

I was contacted by an acquaintance and introduced to a leveraged/trade platform program where I would put 10% (of what I needed) into a personal account with Citi Bank in my name only.  In 90 days, I could then take my money back and receive a loan equal to 10 times my deposit. My money would never be at risk.

This sounds almost incredulous. 1) How do they leverage my money without it being encumbered? 2) How can there be no risks?

Very confused.  Hope you can shine some light on this.  Thank you

Comment: Sounds like scam. Run.

Comment: Rule of thumb: if there is no risk then it is too good to be true. It's probably a scam as Keshlam stated.

Comment: Call Citibank and ask them about it. My guess, if it is a real thing, is that the interest rate will be astronomical, which is where the risk to you comes in.

Answer (score 1):

A "leveraged/trade program"?  What exactly is **that**?  So let me get this straight.  You put just 10% of the total amount of what you're trading into an account with Citi (Citi's going to give you 10-1 leverage on your money...why?), and then in 90 days they'll give you your money back and a loan for ten times the amount?

Either the heat has gotten to me or this is the craziest thing I've read today.

You didn't specify what it is you'd be "trading", and if your "acquaintance" didn't share that with you either then it sounds beyond suspect -- it sounds like total fraud.  I couldn't imagine a scenario whereby Citi would be involved in a scheme like this, whatever "it" is.

I suspect that your "friend" has you opening an account at Citi because it makes the whole scam sound more legitimate by tying to a big bank name.  It might be worth your time to actually call Citi (I looked up their number for you.  It's 1-800-685-0935) and ask *them* about this particular idea.  When they get done snickering, they'll tell you the same thing everyone else is -- **RUN** from this.

You're very right to suspect that you can't leverage money without encumbering it.  What would be the point for someone to essentially give you credit on a 10-to-1 basis and then not encumber the collateral?

If you don't know anything about trading and how leverage works then it would be highly inadvisable for you to jump into something that you don't understand.  Your "acquaintance" may have been sucked into investing their own money, and now they think they're doing you a "favor" by telling you about this "incredible opportunity".  It's how most scams work.  They get the suckers to sign up friends and relatives, because they're playing on the trust between those people.

Stick to what you know or what someone can give you a clear and reasonable explanation of.  And have someone you really *know* and *trust* (preferably a friend or family member who is reasonably successful in managing their own finances) to act as a sounding board when things like this come along to help keep you from doing something stupid that you'll really regret.

Hope this helps.

Good luck!